# How to switch to GitHub mobile website?

Tags: github, mobile

While browsing GitHub from Safari on iOS, I've occasionally switched to desktop version of the website. Now I couldn't find way to switch back to mobile version. Even when opening GitHub in Safari private mode, I'm getting myself on desktop website. How could I bring mobile GitHub back?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cookies and cache?

Comment: Yes, I tried. No effect. Also, cookies shouldn't be shared with websites in private mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct solution to the problem is to add to any of GitHub URLs parameter `mobile` with value `1`, e.g. https://github.com/?mobile=1. That will make GitHub to show mobile version of the website for you (it will remember the parameter, no need to add it each time), until you switch back to desktop version.

However I found no reason for *Switch to mobile version* link is not shown in Safari on iOS as it appears on screenshot posted by @Muhammad in [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56491/how-to-switch-to-github-mobile-website#comment44772_56521) to his answer. It someone know the reason behind it, feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: The solution occasionally stopped to work as of now :-(

Answer (score 14):

I know this is a 5 year old post, but it is still the first Google hit for "GitHub Switch to Mobile Version" and several other variants.  The solution to add "?mobile=1" still works at least in some cases, but there is a more all encompassing one if you want to change the setting across the board.

As of now, if you click "Always Use Desktop Version" you will not get a link to undo that setting. The setting is now saved in your account settings.

[image]

Comment: THIS should be the accepted answer. Just uncheck the above checkbox, click „Update Mobile Setting“ and everything is back to normal. You may need to clear you browser cache though.

Answer (score 4):

Go here and check the mobile settings. Opt into mobile. You may have to toggle it to kick in. 
https://github.com/settings/admin

Comment: This works reliably as of 2020-02-13.

Answer (score 1):

What I've found is that **some** github pages are mobile while others are desktop/full pages.

For example if you go to https://github.com, you'll see the desktop site but if you go to https://github.com/explore, it's a mobile version (Safari on iOS).

So if you're looking at a repository, you'll see a mobile version of the page.

**EDIT**: if you don't see a "switch to mobile" link when you're on /explore. You might have to clear your Safari cookies. To clear Safari cookies, go to Settings -> Safari -> Clear Cookies and Data.

Comment: The problem is that, after I switched to desktop website being on mobile version (there was "Desktop Version" link somewhere in the footer of mobile webpage), I couldn't switch back. Now any page is loaded as desktop version (including Explore and any repo page).

Comment: I see this when I switch to desktop: http://mhmd.us/ZNrx+ 

There's a link to switch to mobile for me.

Comment: Sadly, see no such a link :-( I've tried clearing of the cache. Could you please post URL that link points to? Maybe, it will work for me too.

Comment: it's https://github.com/explore?mobile=1

Comment: Yeah, the link works and leads to mobile version of GitHub. Thanks. My issue now resolved. However, it's still unclear why I don't able to see that 'Switch to mobile version' link.

Comment: You could update the answer to include the link switching to mobile version of GitHub so I would be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Chromium web dev toolbar "Toggle device toolbar"**

It is likely detected from user agent.

Chromium's builtin web dev toolbar can easily switch to a mobile user agent for you:

- Ctrl + Shift + C
- Click toolbar
- Ctrl + Shift + M (or click "Toggle device toolbar" at top left)
- Reload the page

Tested in Chromium 58.